# Могу ли я добавить setInterval для каждого шага for?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for, setinterval

Я захотел повернуть элемент на странице. Чтобы он не поворачивался мгновенно я добавил setInterval, который, как я думал, добавит задержку для каждого шага, но это так не работает. Он добавляет задержку между поворотами на 180deg. Как добавить задержку для каждого градуса?

```js
$('.header').find("li").click(function(){
  for(let i = 0; i <= 180; i++){
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(i);
      $(this).find('.fas').css({
        'transform':'rotate(' + i + 'deg)'
      })
    }, 200);
  }
})
```

Comment: вам каждый раз нужно ставить задержку больше, например `i * 100`

Comment: раз используете `JQUERY`, то не проще ли, юзать `animate` для таких вещей?

Comment: Animate не работает с не-числовыми свойствами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

181 `setInterval`? Вам столько не надо.

```js
$('.header').find("li").click(function(){
  var timer = i => {
    $(this).find('.fas').css({
      'transform':'rotate(' + i + 'deg)'
    });
    if (i < 180)
      setTimeout(timer, 1000, i + 1);
  };
  timer(0);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. 181 действительно не нужен.